# Deploy Eclipse 4.1 Project

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment

I have create a simple program using Eclipse 4.1.. I wanted to build or deploy my project into a .jar. I also added external libraries in my project. I wanted the output same as in Netbeans with the .jar file and lib folder in the dist folder, but there should be also a folder named help and lang.. How can I do this with eclipse?!

Comment: check out the link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#88659

Comment: *"I wanted to build or deploy my project"* If it has a GUI, deploy it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps provided [here](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm).
Or if you don't want to complex things up, select `Runnable JAR file` instead of `JAR file` set the directory where the `.jar` is to be written then click `Finish`.

Eclipse will create the `[Project Name]_lib` directory for the external libraries included in the project.